# JQuery Sliding divs and changing button

Tags: jquery, html, slidetoggle

I have a footer slide toggle funcion, and I want to change on the button. up button, down button.

Please read the codes and you will know, what to want.

```js
$(".footer").click(function() {

  $footer = $(this);
  //getting the prev element
  $content = $footer.prev();
  $button = $footer.find("td");
  //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
  $content.slideToggle(500, function() {
    //execute this after slideToggle is done
    //change text of header based on visibility of content div
    return $content.is(":visible") ? $button.attr("up", "down") : $button.attr("down", "up");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infobar">
  <table class="content">
    content
  </table>
  <table class="footer">
    <td class="up" style=" padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;">
    </td>
  </table>
</div>
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/HAQyK/1652/

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 0):

I changed it to toggleClass instead.  I don't think your attributes will accomplish what you want.  When testing, make sure you let the animation complete.

http://jsfiddle.net/HAQyK/1685/

```js
$(".footer").click(function () {

    $footer = $(this);
    //getting the prev element
    $content = $footer.prev();
  $button = $footer.find("td");
    //open up the content needed - toggle the slide- if visible, slide up, if not slidedown.
    $content.slideToggle(500);
    $button.toggleClass("up down")
});
```

```css
.infobar {
    width:100%;
}
.infobar .content {
 margin-bottom: 0px;
 width: 560px;
 table-layout: fixed;
}
.infobar .footer {
    cursor: pointer;
    font-weight: bold;
 width: 560px;
 background-color: #E9E9E9;
 FONT-FAMILY: Verdana;
    COLOR: #1d1d1d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-right: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-left: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
.up {
 background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/5/50/Green_Arrow_Up.svg/10px-Green_Arrow_Up.svg.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-color: #343434;
 FONT-FAMILY: Verdana;
    COLOR: #1d1d1d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-right: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-left: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
.down {
 background: url(https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Red_Arrow_Down.svg/10px-Red_Arrow_Down.svg.png);
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-position: center;
 background-color: #343434;
 FONT-FAMILY: Verdana;
    COLOR: #1d1d1d;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 8px;
 border-bottom: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-right: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-left: 1px solid #1d1d1d;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 7px;
 border-bottom-right-radius: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="infobar">
<table class="content">
content  
</table>
<table class="footer">
   <td class="up" style=" padding-top: 7px; padding-bottom: 7px;" >
   </td>
 </table>
</div>
```